# How to add Entity Framework Geolocation property in Design Database model

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, geolocation

How can I make an Database Model edmx file that would let me add GeoLocation column to it from design database that would let me generate / reverse engeneering from database.

[This one](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/05/04/spatial-types-in-the-entity-framework.aspx) implies that I would modify it by hand.

Do I need to install a plugin for visual studio ? Do I need to find an open source entity generation tool that would help me?

p.s. i am using this[ADO.net Poco Generator](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/23df0450-5677-4926-96cc-173d02752313)
I use SQL server 2008 and .net framework 4.0

p.s. 2 What about this [reference](http://blog.cincura.net/231242-spatial-data-and-entity-framework-from-real-world-usage/) 

p.s. 3 Here on MSDN are some facts about not supporting this feature http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/sqlspatial/thread/34866400-91e5-4af5-9fee-f7f369aa6a61

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I now the geolocation support in the Entity Framework will be released with .NET 4.5, so until then you will have to do it manually.

The second reference you provide should help you out. What the author describes is a way to store the data in the database, make sure it stays up to date with some triggers and then in the partial class in your code define a property that will convert the data field from your database to actual LatLong data.